# can I use the django comments framework without an attached parent model?

Tags: python, django, comments

I'd like to use the Django comments framework (or something similar) to easily enable comments for my site. According to the Django documentation, a comment thread must be associated with a parent object that is a Django model. (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/comments/).

However, most of my views are rendered using non-model data. In other words I want to be able to add comments to anything that has a unique URL, and have those comments keyed on the URL rather than on an underlying model object. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not using the URL as the model? You can even write a middleware that creates an Url instance upon a page request, if it does not exist yet.

Comment: interesting idea. I'll wait for more responses, in case there is a more out-of-the-box type solution, but otherwise this seems like a reasonable way to implement this kind of functionality.